# MVC Visual Studio add .dbml file in Model Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a Models folder. How do I go about creating a .dbml file underneath so that I can add tables, stored procedures in it. I am using MVC c# with Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In Solution Explorer: Right click on the Models folder.
2. Choose Add -> New Item
3. In the dialog that comes up choose Visual C# -> Data -> LINQ to SQL Classes.

This will create a .dbml file in your Models folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the Models folder in Solution Explorer.
2. Select "**Add...**" -> "**New Item...**".
3. Select the "Data" option from the Left Hand Side and then click Linq to SQL Classes:

[image: DBML]